# Payment processing using JQuery/AJAX

Tags: ajax, payment

I'm planning to work on upgrading the payment processing section of my website to use JQuery's AJAX to submit payment information (Credit Card or ECheck) using AJAX.

Do you think there will be security issues if using AJAX to process payments?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: For starters, it won't work if the browser has JavaScript disabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What types of security measures should I take while developing an ajax-driven application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224165/what-types-of-security-measures-should-i-take-while-developing-an-ajax-driven-app)

Comment: @Matt: that's not much of a security issue, is it :) @Felasfaw Same worries as regular GETs and POSTs, make sure you're using https, sanitize incoming data on the server even if already done on the client.

Comment: Thank you very much! You both have given me a good idea on where to focus before moving on.